# Including `thread` crashes call to assembly

Tags: c++

Running this code crashes while removing `#include <thread>` is fine.

```cpp
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
asm ("foo:ret;");
extern"C" void foo();
int main() {
    clock_t clk = clock();
    foo();
    printf ("%4d ", clock()-clk);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NCsIwDMfvfYpQETpwnjw53cUHkZJ2rmz9oIsiiM9eU1TEXJL/x49gSu0FsZSVCzhfjYUDOW@3Yy9@zkLGxX@Lxmy16YVePCg5xLjPljrZdMLeyeYgTxJu0RngSLHrAoHXLqgGHgJ4cI44nYn3BMe3qr0afZB6pszgwB/WOwNy8@21THHjKUp5AQ)

Is it anything special on function calls when `thread` is included?

Comment: what gcc version is this? no segfault here with 12.2 https://godbolt.org/z/rzsv3cTTn

Comment: seems like 10.4 or earlier segfaults

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So it's just some early bug?

Comment: I locally use the gcc from codeblocks but it's 8.1.0

Comment: I don't know,I know neither c nor asm, your code might have UB, then its not threads fault

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But both 9.5 and 12.2 compiled into same asm